# Why does "RewriteRule (.*)" fails, and RewriteRule .* works?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've placed this .htaccess in my root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule   (.*) public/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

It causes a 500 Internal server error with no explanation.

If I remove the paranthesis it works:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule   .* public/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Why? Aren't paranthesis supposed to be neutral here?

I'm using the latest XAMPP version (Windows).

Comment: Does your public directory have .htaccess and index.html or index.php files?

Comment: I'm kinda surprised the second one works.  At first glance, it looks like both should lead to infinite recursion.

Comment: Oh...and so you know, a 500 often corresponds to a message in Apache's error log.  That ought to tell you what went wrong.  Take a look in `your_xampp_dir/apache/logs/error.log`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex groups are enclosed in round brackets and in this case the expression `.*` matches everything, so the rule is always used.

With the expression in parenthesis, the rule maps to `public/WhateverIsInsideParenthesis`, because `$1` is the back reference to group 1: `(.*)`. The only one in this case.

Without the parenthesis, the rule maps just to `public/`, because there is no group. Nothing is inside parenthesis.

You don't give an example of the request, but for something like:

`http://example.com/folder1/folder2/script1/` the URI-path inside the parenthesis would be `folder1/folder2/script1/` and the substitution URL:

`http://example.com/public/folder1/folder2/script1/`

Therefore, there are several reasons for an error in this case, with or without parenthesis. The request, where the rule is mapping to, loops, etc., all might generate that error.  The 500 Internal Server Error  is the general `HTTP status code` used for everything that goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you put the start character `^` in?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule   ^(.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the parenthesis are neutral for the *pattern*.

But they make a difference, when you use the captured string in the substitution as `$1`. Then the rule is equivalent to either

```
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1
```

or

```
RewriteRule .* public/
```

When you leave out the parenthesis and replace `$1` with `$0`

```
RewriteRule .* public/$0
```

then you have the same error again, this time without parenthesis.